# How to set QTableWidget background transparent in Qt?

Tags: qt, background, transparency, qtablewidget

I am developing an app in which I am using QTableWidgets, and I need to set their background transparent, I have tried to `setStyleSheet "background:transparent;"`, but nothing happened.

Is there any other way to do it?

[image]

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You're on the right track. Try:

```
setStyleSheet("QTableWidget {background-color: transparent;}"
              "QHeaderView::section {background-color: transparent;}"
              "QHeaderView {background-color: transparent;}"
              "QTableCornerButton::section {background-color: transparent;}");
QTableWidget *table = new QTableWidget(latticeView);
table->setRowCount(2);
table->setColumnCount(2);
```

Note that I'm setting the style sheet before creating the table widget. I don't know why, but that seems to be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Using `background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);` in your stylesheet, you can get a transparent table. Also, changing the alpha channel, you can have a great effect on your table.

Example:

```css
background-color: rgba(0,0,0,50);
```

```css
QTableWidget
{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,50);
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    font-size:22px;
}

QTableWidget::item
{
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color:rgba(0,0,0,150);
    text-align:center;
}

QTableWidget::item:hover
{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background: #4B4B4D;
}

QTableWidget::item:selected
{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    background: #4B4B4D;
}

QHeaderView{
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,70);
}

QHeaderView::section,QTableCornerButton:section
{
    text-align:center;
    padding:3px;
    margin:0px;
    color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,70);
    border:1px solid #242424;
    border-radius: 8px;
}

QHeaderView::section:selected
{
    color:#FFFFFF;
    border:1px solid #242424;
}
```